# Need to escape datas when moving them around using mysql itself

Tags: mysql, escaping

It's a no brainer that we have to escape datas when inserting them to MySQL. But once these datas are in the database, is it safe to do something like this ?

```
INSERT INTO daily (lastname,
                   firstname,
                   adress,
                   city)
SELECT lastname,
       firstname,
       adress,
       city)
FROM Users
WHERE id = 36;
```

If it's not, is there a workaround ?

Comment: This is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works great. This is so, because your code doesn't include variables, it is pure SQL code.

But watch out, if you are doing something like `insert into table select * from table where id=$id`, then $id needs to be escaped, because $id is a variable that comes from outside of SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the id, obviously as it doesn't come from the DB, I escape it!